# How can I get Sort Type (sorting method) used in DB2

Tags: database, db2, obiee

I am using OBIEE & DB2. OBIEE uses  SORT_TYPE = "binary";
hence I want to find which sorting Type DB2 uses.
How and where Can I find this info.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

The sort depends on the database locale. When you create a DB2 database, you indicate the locale, and this determines the sort order.

Comment: If I want to find that Locale details then ?
Actually DB2 is installed automatically as part of automated test so want to know all locale and sorting method like binary or which it uses

Comment: db2 get dbm cfg sorry ... means can u tell full procedure ? Thanks

Comment: That is a db2 command. You can execute it from the db2clp (black terminal). You can also get that information via a GUI (DataStudio, etc.): http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0001955.html?cp=SSEPGG_10.5.0%2F3-5-2-4-46&lang=en

Comment: Or you can issue this: SELECT * FROM SYSIBMADM.DBMCFG

Comment: @AngocA That's actually the database (`db`) configuration, not the database manager (`dbm`).

Comment: with "get dbm cfg" and "SELECT * FROM SYSIBMADM.DBMCFG" I could get  max number of tcp connection,I/O block size etc, but not which default sorting technique DB2 uses :'(

Comment: It was my fault as @mustaccion said. Actually, you need to see the "database configuration" (DB) not the "database manager configuration" (DBM).

Comment: What you need to execute is: SELECT DBPARTITIONNUM, NAME, VALUE FROM SYSIBMADM.DBCFG and see the territory and country code.

Comment: i used "get db cfg" & "db2 list tablespaces show detail" but Could not find default sorting method

Comment: Collating sequence: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-0506chong/